# Do EVs take immediate effect?

Tags: pokemon-series

I've read a lot about EV training, and from what I understand, every 4 EV points will give you 1 stat point from the EV (say, 4 EV points in Speed will give me 1 Speed stat point when I level up).

Let's say I have a level 70 Gyarados, feed him all the EV-resetting berries, then battle lots of level 4 Poochyena or some other Pokémon to raise my Attack EVs.

Of course, even if I max out his Attack EVs, he won't be able to level up with that little amount of EXP, so when he does finally level up, will I see `HP + 3, Attack + 65, etc.` or something?

Comment: I removed the `pokemon-emerald` tag and edited your question a little as this isn't Emerald-specific - feel free to roll it back if you want to.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*Notice: This post only applies to games up to HeartGold/SoulSilver. The EV system has changed since Black/White. For more details, see [DragonLord's answer.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/90157/12936)*

---

Technically, every 4 EVs gained will result in 1 extra stat **at level 100**. For example, if you took two level 100 Snorlax, with identical natures and IVs, but one had 4 EVs in Attack and the other had 0 EVs in Attack, the former would have 1 more point in its Attack stat than the latter.

The EV-effected stats gained during level-up don't all happen all at once. DisgruntledGoat described what occurs in a good way:

> On level up, the game will calculate how much of a stat point increase you would have at that level and adds it on. For example, if you have a level 50 Gyarados and you earn 200 EVs (50 stat points), you won't get +1 extra point per level up. Instead, you'll get around +25 on the first level up (because at lv50 you would have earned about half the points), then +1 for roughly every two levels after that.

Of course, if your Gyarados was level 99, had cleared EVs, and then you battled all those low level Pokémon, you would probably see a very large stat boost from 99 to 100.

Comment: From my experience it works like this: On level up, the game will calculate how much of a stat point increase you would have at that level and add it on; it doesn't split your EVs by the levels remaining. For example, if you have a level 50 Gyarados and you earn 200 EVs (50 stat points), you won't get +1 extra point per level up. Instead, you'll get around +25 on the first level up (because at lv50 you would have earned about half the points), then +1 for roughly every two levels after that.

Comment: I have seen this when i was EV training my lv 48 Walrein. When it went to 49, it had +9 Sp At and when it went to 50 I gained +25 Sp At

Comment: Ahh, I wasn't quite sure exactly how it worked. I'll edit that in.

Comment: It used to be this way until Gen V. *cue Genwunners complaining about each new generation of Pokemon*

Comment: That doesn't make the answer bad. Technically, the question was originally for Gen III only, so the answer can't ever be outdated.

Answer (score 15):

**As of Generation V (Black and White), yes.**  EVs are now applied to stats after every battle.  This means that player-visible stat increases may occur when they are not expected, such as an increase in maximum HP after a battle without leveling up—and I've observed this playing Pokémon Black.

**In Generations III and IV, EVs are generally applied only on leveling up**, and Pokémon do not gain EVs when at level 100 or otherwise from a battle that does not yield experience points, except by stat-boosting items.  EVs are applied [when the Pokémon is deposited into and withdrawn from the Pokémon Storage System (box)](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Box_trick) as well, which can be done to force any pending EVs to be applied between level-ups or at level 100.

Since Generation III, every 4 EVs adds one point to a particular stat at level 100.  For lower-level Pokémon, this stat gain is prorated based on the Pokémon's current level (for example, a level 50 Pokémon with 120 EVs for HP gains 15 HP from EVs, rather than 30 at level 100).  Generations I and II use a system called Stat Exp that differs significantly from the current EV system.

See [this Bulbapedia article](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Effort_values) for more information on effort values.

---

**As of Generation VI (X and Y), all EV changes are applied immediately**, regardless of whether they are the result of battle, Super Training or otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, no. The only time you will see the full effect is from 99 to 100.  Otherwise the EV stat bonus is distributed among the number of levels left.

Answer (score 0):

**Generation I and II**

To make the answers complete: I'll talk about generations I and II (So Red, Blue, Green, Yellow, Gold, Silver and Crystal editions).

In generation I and II EVs work a bit diffrently. These are the main differences:

1. There is no cap of 'total' amount of EVs.
2. Defeating an opponent gives you EVs equal to their base stats. So, for example, a Celebi would give you 100 points in everything.
3. Max EVs are 65535 in each statistic.
4. The Stat formula is floor(ceil(min(sqrt(EV), 255)) / 4)

That being said, otherwise the system is similar. You gain points by defeating opponents and these increase your stats. Stat increases are factored in on level up, with some minor *quirks* that have been removed in later generations:

1. Levels gained through the use of the item 'Rare candy' do not factor in any EV gains made later. They do apply your 'existing' EVs. Thus, you may miss out on stat points by using this item while your EVs are not yet maximized.
2. If you store a Pokémon in Bill's PC its stats will be recalculated upon retrieval. This method of applying EVs was removed in later games as there is more memory available to store data about your monsters.

Answer (score -6):

I never saw any EV points applied no matter how much I invested in that, I'm figuring that maybe EV status points will not apply to the game until you have reached a certain point of the storyline, or a certain level, that activates the EV points status system.

Comment: As @Dragonlord pointed out in his answer, in gen 5 (B/W/B2/W2) EVs are applied immediately after combat, **not** at level up. See: [Smogon post](http://www.smogon.com/forums/showthread.php?t=85403), [Bulbapedia entry](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Effort_values#Generation_V)